# Get the parent element of caret position inside iframe (with designmode on) in IE

Tags: javascript

This is a follow-up question to the:
[How do I find out the DOM node at cursor in a browser’s editable content window using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563427/how-do-i-find-out-the-dom-node-at-cursor-in-a-browsers-editable-content-window-u/1563492#1563492)

That was answered by **Tim Down**.

There is a problem getting parent element of caret position (without selecting), inside iframe in IE (in firefox it works great).

Here is the partial code from that answer:

```
   if (ob.document.selection && ob.document.selection.createRange) {         
         range = ob.document.selection.createRange();        
         alert(range.parentElement().innerHTML); //I get blank
         return range.parentElement();    
    }
```

where ob is:

```
document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow;
```

The iframe's outerHtml (for testing):

```
 "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>" +
            "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" +
            "<head>" +
            "<title>testing</title>" +           
            "</head>" +
            "<body><p>some text for testing<b>I am bold</b> more testing</p>"+
            "<p>blablabla</p>" +
            "<p>121213134</p></body>" +
            "</html>");
```

So when you place caret on any word, the result is "blank".

Another issue I would like you to address:
if you select section inside "I am bold", the parent element that being returned is
"I am bold" (the b element).
Is it possible to return the P element instead? (ofcourse it should work for other cases as well)

**Update:**

The call to the selection function is made , temporary, by a simple button that is located on document that hosts the iframe:

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="getElementInRange()"/>
```

Also there is Init() function that run at load that sets iframe's outerHTML (though i don't think it's important):

```
function Init() {
        document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.designMode = "on";


        document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.open("text/html", "replace");
        document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.write(//*Here comes the string from above...*

        document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.close();
    }
```

**Update2:**
I tried adding to the button: unselectable="on", this causes strange anomaly some times it returns the right value ans some times it doesn't  even if the caret in same position!!!

**Update3**
 after more testing I've found out that the "anomaly" happens when iframe loses focus and caret disappears from the iframe after clicking (on what state of click it happens i didn't check)the button (if it disappears the result is blank, if it stays the result is as expected).
So the question is how to keep caret inside iframe NO MATTER WHAT?

Comment: Not sure why it's not working but I have noticed there are two closing body tags in your iframe html: `"<p>blablabla</p></body>" + "<p>121213134</p></body>" +`

Comment: @Andy E, this is a copy&paste error (I pasted in portions) it doesn't appear in the source code. But thanks for that. –

Comment: The code from that question works fine for collapsed (caret) selections in IE, so long as it hasn't lost the selection by the time the code is called. Could you post the code that is making the call to the selection-getting code?

Comment: sure thing, Tim. I will do it as soon as I return to my pc. also please tell how can I get the parent that is not B or I... should I check by node name?

Comment: @markiz: Either `nodeName` or `tagName` would do fine. Are you trying to get hold of the containing block level element? If so and you don't know in advance what your HTML will look like, you'll need a more generic method.

Comment: @tim Down, I guess I will need more generic method though the content of iframe is controlled, I plan to "wrap" every line user inputs (after clicking "enter") with paragraph. So the number of options will be limited (I will think about other options latter), first I need it to work with caret.

Comment: p.s. I added the part you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

> So the question is how to keep caret inside iframe NO MATTER WHAT?

Assign a mousedown event on the button. This will be triggered before caret is removed from iframe.
But it will only work once so its a good idea to save a reference to the object into a variable.

```
$("button").mousedown(function(){ parent = getSelectionContainerElement(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really try the [range classes](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/docs/class_goog_dom_AbstractRange.html) from the [Google Closure library](http://code.google.com/closure/library/).

```
goog.require('goog.dom.Range');
var range = goog.dom.Range.createFromWindow(ob);
return range.getStartNode().parentNode;
```

Comment: I don't want to use any 3-rd party libraries.