# How to tell if caret is within H1 tag?

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

I am building a wysiwyg with Content Editable. I want the Bold button to highlight when the caret is within Bold text, etc. I have that working, but I can't figure out how to do the same for H1 & H2. CommandState doesn't seem to work for those items.

My JS Code:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var isBold = document.queryCommandState("Bold");
    var isItalic = document.queryCommandState("Italic");
    var isUnderlined = document.queryCommandState("Underline");

    if (isBold) {
        $('button[rel=Bold]').addClass('active');
    } else {
    $('button[rel=Bold]').removeClass('active');
    }    
    if (isItalic) {
        $('button[rel=Italic]').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('button[rel=Italic]').removeClass('active');
    }
    if (isUnderlined) {
        $('button[rel=Underline]').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('button[rel=Underline]').removeClass('active');
    }

}, 100);
```

Simplified test case: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/gL4xS/

**How can I highlight the H1 & H2 buttons when the caret is within them and is there a more compact way of writing this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need to get the range in order to do that. You can do that either with `document.selection` or `window.getSelection` depending on the browser you are using. I wouldn't have a continual interval running, but rather listen for `keyup` and `mouseup` on the editable `div`

Here is some sample code to accomplish what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/gL4xS/2/

```
$('#editor').on('keyup', function(){
    rangeMouseup();
});

$('#editor').on('mouseup', function(event){
    $('button').removeClass('active');
    $('button[rel='+event.target.nodeName+']').addClass('active');    
});

function rangeMouseup(){
    if (document.selection){
        $(document.selection.createRange().parentElement()).trigger('mouseup');
    }
    else if (window.getSelection){
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        $(range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode).trigger('mouseup');
        $(range.commonAncestorContainer).trigger('mouseup');
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need this to work for all the parent nodes of the caret then cycle up through the DOM and adjust the styles as needed. http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/gL4xS/5/

```
$('#editor').on('mouseup', function(event){
    $('button').removeClass('active');
    var node = event.target;
    while(node.nodeName != 'DIV'){
        $('button[rel='+node.nodeName+']').addClass('active');
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd love to use this method. Two things though: What if two buttons should be highlighted (bold and italic) at the same time? Also, will this work for other elements like ordered lists? Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/gL4xS/3/

Comment: You can cycle up through the dom and get all the parents of the caret and highlight as needed. The event target is the immediate parent of the caret. I will update answer to show an example.

Comment: I updated my answer and yes this will work for any element in the `div`

Comment: You've definitely answered this. Just wondering if you would know what to set the "rel" to so that justification buttons would work with this?

    <button title="Justify Right" rel="Right" onclick="document.execCommand('justifyRight', false, null);"><i class="icon-align-right"></i></button>

Comment: I believe that command sets the align property of the element. You will have to get the align property of the element and highlight as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current dom element and check if it is h1

```
setInterval(function () {
    var isBold = document.queryCommandState("Bold");
    var isItalic = document.queryCommandState("Italic");
    var isUnderlined = document.queryCommandState("Underline");
    var el = getSelectionContainerElement();
    if($(el).is('h1')){
         $('button[rel="Primary Heading"]').addClass('active');
    }else{
        $('button[rel="Primary Heading"]').removeClass('active');
    }
    if (isBold) {
        $('button[rel=Bold]').addClass('active');
    } else {
    $('button[rel=Bold]').removeClass('active');
    }    
    if (isItalic) {
        $('button[rel=Italic]').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('button[rel=Italic]').removeClass('active');
    }
    if (isUnderlined) {
        $('button[rel=Underline]').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('button[rel=Underline]').removeClass('active');
    }

}, 100)
```

the following function is copied from:[How do I find out the DOM node at cursor in a browser's editable content window using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563427/how-do-i-find-out-the-dom-node-at-cursor-in-a-browsers-editable-content-window)

```
function getSelectionContainerElement() {
    var range, sel, container;
    if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        // IE case
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        return range.parentElement();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt) {
            if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            }
        } else {
            // Old WebKit selection object has no getRangeAt, so
            // create a range from other selection properties
            range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);

            // Handle the case when the selection was selected backwards (from the end to the start in the document)
            if (range.collapsed !== sel.isCollapsed) {
                range.setStart(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
                range.setEnd(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            }
        }

        if (range) {
           container = range.commonAncestorContainer;

           // Check if the container is a text node and return its parent if so
           return container.nodeType === 3 ? container.parentNode : container;
        }   
    }
}
```